# Why is the NavLink redirecting me to the end section of a Components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have been working on a ReactJS based website so I used NavLinks to redirect to the other components and it is working but the problem is it lands me to the very end of the components like if I have a Contact page and I am using `<NavLink to="/contact"> Contact Us </NavLink>` and I have set up a route which will render Contact Component for **/contact**  When I click on this link it will take me to the component but it will show the end of the page say if I have three sections on that contact component so when I click on that NavLink it will take me to the last part of that last section but I want it to show the top of the page the top of the first section of that component. How Can I achieve that? Please Help I didn't found the answer to this anywhere else. *Also I would like to add that the NavLinks I used in navbar are working perfectly fine but all the others are giving that problem I just mentioned and all of them are like exactly same I can't figure out the problem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your `NavLink` reference is to the [React Router's `NavLink`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink).

Essentially your React application is not navigating in the sense that you're loading a new web document (HTTP request). Instead you're swapping out parts of your existing page. That means a lot of state (including scroll position in your question) are preserved.

As such, you'll want to "scroll top" anytime you "navigate." This could be accomplished by adding the following hook to your contact page component:

```js
// Scroll to the top of this page when mounted
useEffect(() => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, []);
```

Note: using `<Route path='/contact' render={() => <ContactPage />} />` won't cause the component to remount and would require another solution.

To achieve this "scroll top" anytime you "navigate" globally in your application consider using the following hooks to "scroll top" when your location changes:

```js
const location = useLocation(); // import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

useEffect(() => {
  // Scroll top when location changes
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, [location]);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out me with this. I placed the global solution where we use the useLocation part in my app.js file and it is working absolutely perfect!